# An OCaml odd thing

Tags: ocaml

Can anyone explain this OCaml toplevel behaviour?

```
# 1________________________________1;;
- : int = 11
```

(The big line is a sequence of underscores: '_')

Out of curiosity, this program compiles under ocamlc, too.

Comment: p.s. the same is true in Perl: `print 1________________________________1;`. Ruby also allows underscores, but not consecutive ones

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Underscores are allowed in numbers (and ignored) in OCaml.  From http://www.cs.ru.nl/~tews/htmlman-3.10/lex.html#xhtoc5:

> For convenience and readability, underscore characters (_) are accepted (and ignored) within integer literals.

Comment: OK, unexpected. But I guess people may want to write 1234567890 as 1_234_567_890. Interesting...

Comment: @Surikator: I think that was the intention.  Just below where I quoted, `_` is allowed in floating-point literals as well (and also ignored there).

Comment: The following mentions the lexical convention for floats and integers (notice where the optional _ character is; even 1___ works.): http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html

Answer (score 5):

That's a very useful feature to avoid bugs and ease the reading of big integers:

`1_000_000_000` is easier to read than `100000000` (did you notice I forgot a zero ?).

Answer (score 4):

There is several programming language that accepts the underscore character as a non significant character in an integer. Ada, Perl, OCaml and probably some other language use it to separate thousand, millions and billions... but you can use `_` anywhere inside the integer.